# SQL Create Groups Using a Start And End Column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following data in a table and I'm trying to work out if SQL will allow me to group records using one of my columns `EndOfEventFlag`. Each row has a corresponding `ChannelID` and `PacketSequenceNumber`. I can partially group and order the data by these columns but I really want to group records between from the first value where `EndOfEventFlag=false` and the next value where `EventOfEventFlag=true`. So from the example below, the first group would be all the rows from `PacketSequenceNumber` 24926 to 24932, followed by the next group 26319-26325. I need to group them first before I can aggregate them using a UDF I've written in BigQuery.

| ChannelID | PacketSequenceNumber | EndOfEventFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 208 | 24926 | false |
| 208 | 24927 | false |
| 208 | 24928 | false |
| 208 | 24929 | false |
| 208 | 24930 | false |
| 208 | 24931 | false |
| 208 | 24932 | true |
| 208 | 26319 | false |
| 208 | 26320 | false |
| 208 | 26321 | false |
| 208 | 26322 | false |
| 208 | 26323 | false |
| 208 | 26324 | false |
| 208 | 26325 | true |
| 208 | 26353 | false |
| 208 | 26354 | false |
| 208 | 26355 | false |
| 208 | 26356 | false |
| 208 | 26357 | false |
| 208 | 26358 | false |
| 208 | 26359 | true |
| 208 | 26709 | false |
| 208 | 26710 | false |
| 208 | 26711 | false |
| 208 | 26712 | false |
| 208 | 26713 | false |
| 208 | 26714 | false |
| 208 | 26715 | true |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have bigquery, but this works in T-SQL, perhaps you can adapt it? If you do and need to make adjustments to get it to work, please reply so I can update my answer to better serve future users who find this by tag.

The approach is to generate impulse integer "edges" (value of 1) of your groups, but push them forward by 1 row so a 'true' gets grouped with the previous run of 'false' (value of 0). Once you have edges, compute a running total of integer edges, the impulse of 1 will start a new group that stays the same until the next impulse.

```
--BEGIN sample data
;with cteSampleData as ( 
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
    ('208', '24926', 'false')
    , ('208', '24927', 'false')
    , ('208', '24928', 'false')
    , ('208', '24929', 'false')
    , ('208', '24930', 'false')
    , ('208', '24931', 'false')
    , ('208', '24932', 'true')
    , ('208', '26319', 'false')
    , ('208', '26320', 'false')
    , ('208', '26321', 'false')
    , ('208', '26322', 'false')
    , ('208', '26323', 'false')
    , ('208', '26324', 'false')
    , ('208', '26325', 'true')
    , ('208', '26353', 'false')
    , ('208', '26354', 'false')
    , ('208', '26355', 'false')
    , ('208', '26356', 'false')
    , ('208', '26357', 'false')
    , ('208', '26358', 'false')
    , ('208', '26359', 'true')
    , ('208', '26709', 'false')
    , ('208', '26710', 'false')
    , ('208', '26711', 'false')
    , ('208', '26712', 'false')
    , ('208', '26713', 'false')
    , ('208', '26714', 'false')
    , ('208', '26715', 'true')
    ) as SampleData(ChannelID, PacketSequenceNumber, EndOfEventFlag) 
) --END sample data
, cteStep1 as (--First step of the solution, lump each "true" with previous "false", if any
--note that this could probably be rolled into one step, but this is easier to read and debug and the 
--query optimizer will ensure you don't takje a significant performance hit
    SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN LAG(EndOfEventFlag, 1, 'false') 
                OVER (--PARTITION BY ChannelID --Uncomment the PARTITION to group by channel
                    ORDER BY PacketSequenceNumber) = 'true' 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as GroupEdge
    FROM cteSampleData as S
)
SELECT ChannelID, PacketSequenceNumber, EndOfEventFlag
--Now generate the group by performing a running total of the edges
--each edge (the first value after a 'true') will start a new group
--this approach correctly handles 2 consecutrive 'true' values, it makes a run of 1
    , SUM(GroupEdge) OVER (--PARTITION BY ChannelID --Uncomment the PARTITION to group by channel
                                ORDER BY PacketSequenceNumber) as GroupNumber
FROM cteStep1 as x
```

This gives result:

| ChannelID | PacketSequenceNumber | EndOfEventFlag | GroupNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 208 | 24926 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24927 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24928 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24929 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24930 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24931 | false | 0 |
| 208 | 24932 | true | 0 |
| 208 | 26319 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26320 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26321 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26322 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26323 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26324 | false | 1 |
| 208 | 26325 | true | 1 |
| 208 | 26353 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26354 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26355 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26356 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26357 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26358 | false | 2 |
| 208 | 26359 | true | 2 |
| 208 | 26709 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26710 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26711 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26712 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26713 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26714 | false | 3 |
| 208 | 26715 | true | 3 |

Comment: YW and thanks for letting me and future users know this works for Bigquery!

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple "one step" solution (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT *, 
  COUNTIF(EndOfEventFlag) OVER win AS GroupNumber
FROM your_table 
WINDOW win AS (
  PARTITION BY ChannelID 
  ORDER BY PacketSequenceNumber 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]